# iOS playground error of lower deployment target

Tags: ios, swift, scheduler

I'm trying to use **Scheduler** in iOS playground, but get an error like this:

```
expression failed to parse:
error: Playground.playground:46:8: error: 'Scheduler' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer; clients of '__lldb_expr_10' may have a lower deployment target
    S: Scheduler, S.SchedulerTimeType == SchedulerTimeType, S.SchedulerOptions == SchedulerOptions
```

I don't know where to set the deployment target, cause it's an independent file, not a workspace or a project. Anyone can help?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Xcode 14.1 macos 13.0.1 (22A400) with m1 chip

Comment: Hi Santiago, could you find any work around for this?

Comment: not yet, just try to use swift composable arch and found this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Playground, you need to explicitly import or denote all that you are going to use.

So in your case you can add @available(iOS 13.0, *) attribute to the property of function which is using Scheduler.

I've got the same problem when was trying to use CGFloat in Playground. And this helps.

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func width(string: String, withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
    let boundingBox = string.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
    
    return ceil(boundingBox.width)
}
```

Comment: Is this a recent change? It's been a while since I last worked with playgrounds, but I don't remember any "...is only available in..." errors before.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumble upon the same issue with a weirder error like this:

```
MyPlayground.playground:119:21: error: 'URL' is only available in iOS 8.0 or newer; clients of '__lldb_expr_21' may have a lower deployment target
```

If fact, this is due to the `public` modifier. Just remove all `public` modifier from your playground code and you'll get rid of this error without the need to put `@available` attributes anywhere, which isn't very practical.

Hope it helps!